# Why can't access variables? 500 Interal Server Error

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, web2py

I have a list that is passed to an ajax function. First grab all the quantities from each input into a list, then I proceed to feed the list into a function which should return and update the total field. I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error with any operation on itemQuantities. How come?

In HTML:

```
var quantityElements = []

function countQuantityElements() {
    quantityElements = []
    $("[id='itemQuantity']").each(function() {
        quantityElements.push($(this).val());
    });
}

$("#itemContainer").on('change', '#itemQuantity', function() {
    countQuantityElements();
    ajax_calculateTotal(quantityElements);
});

function ajax_calculateTotal(quantities) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        method:'post', url:'{{=URL('calculateTotal')}}',
        data:{'quantities':quantities},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#total").attr("value", data);
        }
    });
}
```

And in my controller:

```
def calculateTotal():
    vars = request.post_vars
    itemQuantities = vars.quantities
    itemTotal = 0
    for i in range(len(itemQuantities)):
        itemTotal += itemQuantities[i]
    return str(itemTotal)
```

Comment: try to get full traceback from your app, it's not correct way try to answer based only on HTTP 500 exception

Comment: one thing, thats definitely wrong is, that you won't get numbers from post_vars, only strings, and then summation fails, btw. use the `sum`-function.